# Function won't work when clicking it, nothing happens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Yet again another problem sorry. I can't figure out why once I click on the browse our products section, it should then animate and reveal some images but currently, it is not doing anything of the sort. but, it's not erring in web storm. I am really struggling to identify where the problem is occurring.

```js
var $menuWrap = $('#menu-wrap'),
    $body = $('body'),
    $menuTitle = $('#menu-title'),
    $close = $('#close'),
    $menuCards = $('.menu-card'),
    $menuInner = $('#menu-inner'),
    $menuLink = $('#menu-link');

setCardHeight();
$(window).resize(setCardHeight);

$menuLink.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showOverlay();
});

$close.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    hideOverlay();
});

function showOverlay() {
    $body.addClass('menu-on');
    $menuWrap.addClass('display').addClass('visible');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $menuTitle.addClass('on');
        $close.addClass('on');
    }, 200);
    $menuCards.each(function(i) {
        var $card = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $card.addClass('on');
        }, 200 + 50 * i);
    });
}

function hideOverlay() {
    $body.removeClass('menu-on');
    $menuCards.removeClass('on');
    $menuTitle.removeClass('on');
    $close.removeClass('on');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $menuWrap.removeClass('display').removeClass('visible');
    }, 350);
}

function setCardHeight() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var topVal;
    if (windowWidth >= 1300) {
        topVal = ($(window).height() - 700) / 2;
    } else {
        topVal = ($(window).height() - 200 - (windowWidth / 1300 * 513)) / 2;
    }
    if (topVal < 10) {
        topVal = 10;
    }
    $menuInner.css('top', topVal);
}
```

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #333;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Gotham Rounded", "Proxima Nova",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color:#fff;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top:50px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 2100;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    letter-spacing: .125em;
    transform: translateY(0);
    transition: all .4s;
    transition-delay: .1s;
}
.menu-on #logo  {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
}
#menu-link {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    z-index: 2100;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    transform: translateY(0);
    transition: all .35s;
}
#menu-link:hover {
    color: #ffe22d;
}
.menu-on #menu-link  {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
}
.menu-sub {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    display: block;
    opacity: .6;
    letter-spacing: .125em;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.menu-main {
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: .09em;
    font-weight: 500;
}

#bk-wrap {
    width: 120%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(IMG_2978.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
    left:-70px;
    top:0;
    z-index: 1;
    transform:  translateX(0) scale(1);
    transition: all .5s;
}

#bk-no-blur, #bk-blur, #bk-shadow {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#bk-shadow {
    index: 1;
    position: fixed;
}
#bk-blur {
    background: url(IMG_2978.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: opacity .4s;
}

.menu-on #bk-wrap {
    transform:  translateX(200px) scale(1.3);
}
.menu-on #bk-blur {
    opacity: 1;
}


#bk-shadow {
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 500px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    z-index: 100;
}
/*.menu-on #bk-shadow  {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 500px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}*/

#menu-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2000;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s;
}
#menu-wrap.display {
    display: block;
}
#menu-wrap.visible {
    opacity: 1;
}
#menu-inner {
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 70px;
}
#menu-title {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding:30px 8px;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s;
    top:10px;
    transform:   translateY(0);
    position: relative;
}
#menu-title.on {
    opacity: 1;
    transform:   translateY(-10px);
}

#close {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    width: 43px;
    height: 43px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top:40px;
    opacity: 0;
    transform:   translateY(0);
    transition: all .3s;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 7px 0 0 3px;
}
#close:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}
#close.on {
    opacity: 1;
    transform:   translateY(-10px);
}
#menu-cards {
    background: transparent;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
#menu-cards:before, #menu-cards:after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
#menu-cards:after {
    clear: both;
}

.menu-card {
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 8px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s;
    transform:  scale(.975);
}
.menu-card.on {
    opacity: 1;
    transform:  scale(1);
}
.menu-card:hover {
    transform: scale(1.025);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-card img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.menu-card h3 {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 17px;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 758px) {
    #menu-inner {
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
    .menu-on #bk-wrap {
        transform:  translateX(100px) scale(1.3);
    }
    #menu-title {
        padding-left: 55px;
    }
    .menu-card {
        padding: 4px;
    }
    .menu-card h3 {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">

    </script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Jacinto</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="bk-wrap">
    <div id="bk-no-blur"></div>
    <div id="bk-blur"></div>
</div>

<div id="bk-shadow"></div>
<p id="logo">meili</p>
<a href="#" id="menu-link">
    <span class="menu-sub">Browse our</span>
    <span class="menu-main">Products</span>
</a>
<div id="menu-wrap">
    <div id="menu-inner"></div>
    <h1 id="menu-title">Products</h1>
    <a href="#" id="close">x</a>
    <div id="menu-cards">
        <div class="menu-card">
            <img src="IMG_0437.jpg" alt="clothes">
            <h3>Clothes</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-card">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523730205978-59fd1b2965e3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=691&q=80" alt="accessories">
            <h3>Accessories</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-card">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532040675891-5991e7e3d0cd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=675&q=80" alt="shoes">
            <h3>Shoes</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add the JavaScript file in the HTML document

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/ndmr3a9b/.

Comment: I edited your code in a snippet & put dummy images, it's as @JacobLockard said, working for me too.